# Is it possible to use IS NOT DISTINCT FROM in an exclusion constraint?

Tags: postgresql, constraints, postgresql-9.5

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE claim (
    claim_number TEXT NOT NULL,
    line_id TEXT,
    process TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

I want to add a constraint to it so that the combination of claim_number and line_id is always unique.

In most cases line_id is null and there will only be a single row for that claim number.  In some cases there will be multiple rows for a given claim_number and in those cases line_id will always contain a value.  The goal here is to be able to have a constraint that forces a unique combination on the (claim_number, line_id) combo so that I can use it as a conflict target in an `INSERT...ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` statement so that the process column can be updated. A UNIQUE constraint won't work because it doesn't evaluate NULL = NULL, which makes sense, but isn't what I need.

I have tried adding an exclusion constraint such as:

```
ALTER TABLE claim
ADD EXCLUDE ( claim_number WITH =,
              line_id WITH IS NOT DISTINCT FROM);
```

But that fails with:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IS"
```

Is there a way to use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` in an exclusion constraint?

Comment: Whyis line_id NULLable? Why is it text? (it appears to be a number)

Comment: A simple workaround would be to define a default value that would be your equivalent to a NULL value that you would of course handle in your application. Also wondering why those columns are TEXT...

Comment: @wildplasser I put all IDs as TEXT, always, so that values that have leading zeros don't end up changed. For instance a SSN such as 009543219 shouldn't be stored as an INTEGER because it will lose leading zeros. Also, the data in claim_number is alphanumeric.  Basically, if I'm not doing math with it then it shouldn't be a number.

Comment: @wildplasser The line_id column is nullable because I'm not in control of the source data I just need to work with it and that is how the data is when I receive it.

Comment: An exclusion constraint can't be used for an `on conflict` target

Comment: @GregoryArenius : if you are not in control of the domain, it should not be (part of) the primary key. Use a surrogate key pointing to a table with your (UNIQUE)  text keys. That will at least avoid key-updates (on the text "key") cascading through all your (FK) indexes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Could you point me to where in the docs it talks about which indexes can be used as conflict targets? I feel like I've read them fairly thoroughly but I seem to have missed this.  The manual is amazing but its dense and sometimes easy to miss the piece that pertains to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @joop Yes, I can make a surrogate key, but that doesn't help when I get new data in, because it won't have that key.  This is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Well, IMHO the real problem is: you cannot put constraints on imported(external) data. You can import them into a tempory table, and use that to insert/update your final tables,  imposing *your* constraints

Answer (score 1):

In MSSQL Server, this is done using a Filtered Unique Index, where the filter predicate is that it only indexes rows with non-`NULL` values.

I'm not a PostgreSQL expert, but Googling shows it's possible using a "Partial Index": https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_claim_lines ON claim ( claim_number, line_id )
    WHERE line_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I'm not sure that will work for this instance because I need the index in question to cover the entire table, not just part of it, in order for it to work as needed with the `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` statement.

Comment: @GregoryArenius This index does cover the entire table. This index is not used for searching or query performance, only to enforce the `UNIQUE` constraint for `claim_number`+`line_id` when `line_id` is specified. Perhaps there's a better approach than using `ON CONFLICT`?

Comment: @GregoryArenius: the partial index would prevent (`claim_1`, `line_1`) to be inserted a second time. But the drawback is that a partial index (like an exclusion constraint)  can't be used for an `on conflict` clause. And you can't create a unique _constraint_ using a partial index. The bottom line is: you can prevent those rows from being inserted, but you can't use `on conflict` with that restriction